# Did regional county courts used to be separate courts?

Tags: england-and-wales, county-court

The county court of England and Wales is now one big single court that sits in many locations but these are colloquially referred to as though separate courts (Bristol county court, Bath county court, etc.) though these are in fact merely distinct as hearing centres of *the* national unified county court. When did this now-colloquialism cease being an accurate representation of the reality?

Answer (score 6):

https://www.judiciary.uk/about-the-judiciary/history-of-the-judiciary-in-england-and-wales/history-of-the-judiciary/

> In 2013 the individual County Courts were unified to form a single County Court for England and Wales.